# How to find path to currently running program in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, path

I need working C++ code that lets me know the path to the currently running program in Mac OS X. (Not the current working dir)

I found references only for linux and Win in SO/other sites.

Yours sincerely,
Arvind.

Answer (score 0):

See [`executablePath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1409078-executablepath?language=objc) or [`executableURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1410470-executableurl?language=objc) of [`mainBundle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1410786-mainbundle?language=objc).